# Ceiling light wire/hook up

Tags: wiring, ceiling, circuit-breaker

Hello I hooked up a new ceiling light, There are 3 different color wires. Red,Black,and white, 2 of each color wire. I wired each color wire to there self and then wired the light wires (copper color) to them. There are 2 light switches in my house that operate this light. One light switch works great. but the other when turned on trips the breaker. I'm going to replace the breaker switch soon, but if that does not work, how should I wire the light?

Comment: Why would you replace the breaker if flipping the switch trips it?? Sounds like it's doing it's job.

Comment: Wire the light exactly how it was wired before.

Comment: Can you provide a photo, or diagram of the wiring? How exactly did you connect the light wires?  What does the wiring look like at the two switches?

Comment: Did one of the white wires have colored tape or paint on it?

Comment: (0) You can do this. Homeowners solve problems like this all the time. But you cannot just hook up the wires and hope for the best. - You will need any one of three things to accomplish your goals functionally and safely: (1) Mechanical ability, in particular a talent for electric circuit analysis; (2) Communication skills, with patience to engage in conversation here until you get a complete answer; or (3) Money.

Comment: (1) *Mechanical ability.* Turn the circuit breaker off before touching any of the wiring. Disconnect the connections you made. Take the cover plates off the two switch boxes and pull the switches out so you can see the wires. Obtain or make a contact voltage detector. Find out where the mains power is fed into the circuit. Read up on 3-way switches until you fully understand them. Ask questions here to fill in any details.

Comment: (2) *Communication skills.* No one could answer your question with only the information you've provided so far. There are several regulars here who enjoy teaching how to solve wiring problems but you'll have to engage in a conversation, either in chat or here in the comments. Part of the conversation will involve defining common terms, and part may be about how to find out things, or how to add a diagram to your question.

Comment: (3) *Money.* Hire a licensed professional electrician.